# Aligning multiple xts time series plots

Tags: r, plot, xts, zoo

I have an xts object with 4 columns.  The first 3 columns are the mean and lower and upper confidence bounds for a proportion.  The 4th column is the sample size.  Since the scales are different, I thought it would make sense to plot the first 3 columns on one graph, and plot the 4th on a separate graph, right below it.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Here's code to build an xts object that's like the one I have:

```
startTime = Sys.time()
n = 10
d = seq(startTime,startTime+n*24*60*60,by="1 day")
a = sample(10000,length(d),replace=TRUE)
p = runif(length(d))
l = p/2
u = p+(p+1)/2
x= xts(p,d)
x = cbind(x,l,u,a)
colnames(x) = c("prop","low","high","size")
```

Answer (score 10):

It's easy to do if you use `plot.zoo`.  Something like this will get you started:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
plot.zoo(x, screens=c(1,1,1,2))
```

There are tons of examples in `?plot.zoo`; make sure to check them out.

Comment: how to add legends to each plot?